# Matrix system of equations

Tags: equation-solving, matrix

Given:

```
D1={{1,0,0,0},{0,-1,0,0},{0,0,-1,0},{0,0,0,1}}
D2={{1/4,Sqrt[3]/4,Sqrt[3]/4,3/4},{-(Sqrt[3]/4),1/4,-(3/4),Sqrt[3]/4},{-(Sqrt[3]/4),-(3/4),1/4,Sqrt[3]/4},{3/4,-(Sqrt[3]/4),-(Sqrt[3]/4),1/4}};
B1={{1,0,0,0},{0,-1,0,0},{0,0,1,0},{0,0,0,-1}};
B2={{1,0,0,0},{0,1,0,0},{0,0,-(1/2),-(Sqrt[3]/2)},{0,0,Sqrt[3]/2,-(1/2)}};
```

How do I solve the following system of equations `C^-1.D1.C==B1` and `C^-1.D2.C==B2` in order to find `C`

Comment: If you multiply both by C it becomes a pair of linear systems.

Answer (score 2):

- `Reduce` find all the solutions and  `FindInstance`  find some examples. Here we replace `c^-1` to `Inverse[c]`.

```
eqns = {Inverse@c . D1 . c == B1, Inverse@c . D2 . c == B2};
solution = Reduce[eqns, c ∈ Matrices[{4, 4}]]

m = Array[Indexed[c, {##}] &, {4, 4}];
sols = FindInstance[solution, Flatten@m, Reals, 5];
examples = Array[Indexed[c, {##}] &, {4, 4}] /. sols;
MatrixForm /@ examples
{Inverse@c . D1 . c == B1, Inverse@c . D2 . c == B2} /. c -> m /. sols
```

[image]